# In which cases va_list should be used

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I made a small C library that implements graph theory algorithms and binds them for use in Python.

I send it to a friend to check it and he told me that `va_list` is "dangerous" and must not be used in this kind of project.

So the question is. In which cases `va_list` should be used?

Comment: If you need functions that take a variable number of arguments in C, you have to use `va_list` -- that's the only way to do it.  There *are* certain ways in which variable-argument-list functions in C are unsafe, but if you need them, you need them.  I can't give any advice about whether they are necessary, without seeing what you are using them for.

Comment: This is about a C library. You should remove the `c++` tag. The answers will be not suitable.

Comment: if the arguments are of the same type or in a class hierarchy with a common base class or interface, you could always just pass an array as an argument instead of using va_list

Comment: @pmr the c++ tag is there only because va_list is also accessible from c++ code.

Comment: @marcushatchenson Yes, but in C++ (especially C++11) you would get different answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem I see is that there's no guarantee that you really got the number of arguments that you were expecting, and no way to check for that. This makes errors undetectable, and undetectable errors are, obviously, the most dangerous kind. `va_arg` is also not type-safe, which means that if you pass a `double` and expect an `unsigned long long`, you'll get garbage instead of a good-looking integer, and no way to detect it at compile-time. (It becomes much more of a mess when the types don't even have the same size).

Depending on the data you deal with, this may be more or less of a problem. If you pass pointers, it becomes almost instantly fatal to omit an argument because your function will retrieve garbage instead, and this *could* (if the planets are properly aligned) become a vulnerability.

If you pass "regular" numeric data, it then depends on if the function is critical. In some cases you can easily detect an error looking at the function's output, and in some practical cases it really isn't that much of a problem if the function fails.

It all revolves about if you're afraid of forgetting arguments yourself, actually.

C++11 has a variadic template feature that allows you to treat an arbitrary number of parameters in a safe way. If the step from C to C++ isn't hurting too much, you could look into it.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, `va_list` should never be used, as it provides better alternative called [*variadic template*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), which is typesafe whereas `va_list` is not.

In C, you could use `va_list` when you need variadic function, but be careful, as it is not typesafe.

And yes, your friend is correct: `va_list` is *dangerous*. Avoid it as much as possible.

In C and C++03, the standard library function `printf` is implemented using `va_list`, that is why C++03 programmers usually avoid using this, for it is not typesafe.

But a variadic **typesafe** `printf` could be implemented in C++11, as: (taken from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template))

```
void printf(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {
      if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%')
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid format string: missing arguments");
      std::cout << *s++;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printf(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    while (*s) {
      if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%') {
         std::cout << value;
         ++s;
         printf(s, args...); 
         return;
      }
      std::cout << *s++;
    }
    throw std::logic_error("extra arguments provided to printf");
}
```

Comment: how would you use variadic template if function is a lambda function?

Comment: @serup: I didn't get your question. Are you asking something pertaining to the topic and my answer here, or in general?

Comment: you say it provides better alternative called variadic template, however would like to know how a variadic template could be used on a lambda function - your example here is a normal function, however the usage of argument transfer in lambda functions is a bit difficult, unless the better alternative you talk of could be used

Comment: @serup: Where did *lambda* came from? Like I asked, are you talking something pertaining to the topic? As for lambda, explore variadic lambda in C++14.

Comment: actually this topic does not state the usage of lambda functions, so no and yes - I would like to know if it is at all possible to use this solution on lambda functions or if I have to open a new question

Comment: @serup: As you see, the solution needs *two* functions to iterate over the variadic args and then does the desired things one at a time. In lambda-case, the scenario of *pair* of functions working together makes the situation a bit difficult and isn't straightforward, in C++14 (note that there is no variadic lambda in C++11). However, in C++17, you would be able to do this, with the help of `constexpr if` (I guess). I've not tried that though. But I'm hopeful. You may ask a question and tag your question with C++17.

Answer (score 1):

`va_list` has some disadvanges that are related to the underspecification of the function arguments:

- when calling such a function the compiler doesn't know what types of
  arguments are expected, so the standard imposes some "usual
  conversion" before the arguments are passed to the function. E.g all
  integers that are narrower than `int` are promoted, all `float` are
  promoted to `double`. In some border case you'd not received what you
  wanted in the called function.
- In the called function you tell the compiler what type of argument
  you expect and how much of them. There is no guarantee that a caller get's it right.

If you pass in the number of arguments anyhow and these are of the same known type you could just pass them in with a temporary array, written for C99:

```
void add_vertices(graph G, vertex v, size_t n, vertex neigh[n]);
```

you would call this something like that

```
add_vertices(G, v, nv, (vertex []){ 3, 5, 6, 7 });
```

If that calling convention looks too ugly to you, you could wrap it in a macro

```
#define ADD_VERTICES(G, V, NV, ... ) add_vertices((G), (V), (NV), (vertex [NV]){ __VA_ARG__ })

ADD_VERTICES(G, v, nv, 3, 5, 6, 7);
```

here the `...` indicates a similar concept for macros. But the result is much safer since the compiler can do a type check and this is not delayed to the execution.

Comment: I see that you had a problem with this too. http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/avoid-writing-va_arg-functions/

Comment: Since you already found that :) you could also have a look at the first link on that page (if you haven't yet) to see how you can even avoid to count the number of arguments.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to implement a function in C with variable argument count, you can use va_list. For example, printf uses va_list. Not sure why it can be dangerous.

Comment: Have you ever used the wrong type specifier in a `printf` format string? Or worse, in a `scanf` format string?

Comment: @Fed Larson, compiler makers got your point and now gcc and clang emit warnings about wrong data types for printf patterns. It still is a problem for other functions though.

Comment: @FredLarson, Yes, now I understand the danger of using va_list.